# Lighter color in datagrid alternate row color

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I have a datagrid where I use a color theme to set the `row hilite color`:

```
  set the dgprop["hilite color"] of group "dg_xxx" to color1 -- #dc8400
```

Now I would like to have the `alternate row color` based on `color1` but with a lighter note (i.E. 30% lightened up is `#FFD14D`).

Is there a way to do something like the following with RGB or HEX calculations to make it dynamically changing when `color1` changes?

```
set the dgprop["alternate row color"] of group "dg_xxx" to (color1 - 30%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function returns a shade, which is calculated by adding a share s of the remaining distance to white. Warning 1: basically you increase the brightness by using this function and you may end up with an ugly type of grey and eventually white. Warning 2: s and -s don't give exactly reverse results.

```
function rgbShade
  if the paramCount is 4 then
    put param(1) into r
    put param(2) into g
    put param(3) into b
    put param(4) into s
  else
    put item 1 of param(1) into r
    put item 2 of param(1) into g
    put item 3 of param(1) into b
    put param(2) into s
  end if
  put r+(255-r)*s into r
  put g+(255-g)*s into g
  put b+(255-b)*s into b
  return r,g,b
end rgbShade
```

Usage:

```
get rgbShade("123,45,67",0.2) // increase of 20% of remaining distance
put rgbShade(123,45,67,0.2) into myShade // same as above
```

Example:

```
set the dgprop["hilite color"] of group "dg_xxx" to color1 -- #dc8400
set the dgprop["alternate row color"] of group "dg_xxx" to rgbShade(color1,.3)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Easier than I thought :-)